# Как открыть HTML-страницу из desktop приложения программно?

Tags: java, html, javafx

Допустим, у меня есть приложение с `MenuBar`и в этом меню есть пункт "справка".

Я хочу, чтобы по нажатию на этот пункт справка открывалась в отдельном окне. Если мануал для пользователя представляет собой HTML-страницу, загруженную на хостинг, то как ее можно открыть программно?

Comment: Чтобы открылась страница в браузере по-умолчанию?

Comment: @gil9red да, именно так

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## javafx:

```
getHostServices().showDocument("https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1093315/");
```

---

## awt:

Мне понравилось такое [решение](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5226244/5909792):

- Проверяем, что такая возможность доступна
- Открываем ссылку в браузере по-умолчанию

Пример:

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.net.URI;

// ...

if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported() && Desktop.getDesktop().isSupported(Desktop.Action.BROWSE)) {
    Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1093315/"));
}
```

Comment: Меня смущает import java.awt,Desktop. Зачем мешать awt и fx?

Comment: Хороший вопрос, попробуйте `getHostServices().showDocument("https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1093315/");` (https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/HostServices.html#showDocument(java.lang.String))